# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when retrieving arguments inside decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I am trying to write a decorator for async methods that times out the method after a certain time period. The decorator takes an argument (the index of the config object that includes the timeout value), and should cancel the method after a timeout if specified, or return the original method.

This is my function:

```
export function timeoutWrapper(requestsConfigIndex: number): Function {
  return function setMethodTimeout(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
  ): PropertyDescriptor {
    descriptor.value = function() {
      const context = this;
      const args = arguments;
      const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

      // retrieve requestsConfig from arguments...
      const getTimeout = (args: IArguments): number | undefined => {
        const requestConfig = args[requestsConfigIndex];
        if (requestConfig) {
          return requestConfig.timeout;
        }
        return undefined;
      };

      const timeout = getTimeout(args);

      if (timeout) {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
          axios.CancelToken.source().cancel();
          clearTimeout(timer);
          throw new Error('The method did not finish before the specified timeout.');
        }, timeout);
        originalMethod
          .apply(context, args)
          .then((result: any) => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            return result;
          })
          .catch((e: Error) => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            throw e;
          });
      } else {
        originalMethod.apply(context, args);
      }
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

I am using the decorator to wrap one of my class methods:

```
 @timeoutWrapper(2)
  public async getMap(params: GetMapParams, api: ApiType, reqConfig?: RequestConfiguration): Promise<Blob> {
    // ...
  }
```

However, when called without a timeout, I am getting the following error when running unit tests:

```
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

      48 |     descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
      49 |   ): PropertyDescriptor {
    > 50 |     descriptor.value = function() {
         |                        ^
      51 |       const context = this;
      52 |       const args = arguments;
      53 |       const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

      at WmsLayer.descriptor.value (src/utils/cancelRequests.ts:50:24)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**descriptor.value** is being called inside its own definitation, so it is causing a never ending recursion, hence causing a Maximum call stack size exceeded error.